Python package intallation for mysql
try to install the Flask-MySQLdb package for python flask project. please help to fixed this error. Flask-MySQLdb

Collecting flask-mysqldb   Using cached
Flask_MySQLdb-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB) Requirement
already satisfied: Flask>=1.0.4 in
./.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages (from flask-mysqldb) (3.1.0)
Collecting mysqlclient>=2.2.0 (from flask-mysqldb)   Using cached
mysqlclient-2.2.6.tar.gz (91 kB)   Installing build dependencies ...
done   Getting requirements to build wheel ... error   error:
subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [35 lines of output]
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
Trying pkg-config --exists libmariadb
Command 'pkg-config --exists libmariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
Trying pkg-config --exists perconaserverclient
Command 'pkg-config --exists perconaserverclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kaushal/Flutter Projet/python/first_project/flask-example/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py",
line 353, in 
main()
~~~~^^
File "/Users/kaushal/Flutter Projet/python/first_project/flask-example/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py",
line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/kaushal/Flutter Projet/python/first_project/flask-example/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py",
line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
File "/private/var/folders/bm/yl1wn9ds3pd5569czp8t84nh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8h0okzb/overlay/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py",
line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/private/var/folders/bm/yl1wn9ds3pd5569czp8t84nh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8h0okzb/overlay/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py",
line 304, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
File "/private/var/folders/bm/yl1wn9ds3pd5569czp8t84nh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8h0okzb/overlay/lib/python3.13/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py",
line 320, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 155, in 
File "", line 49, in get_config_posix
File "", line 28, in find_package_name
Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
[end of output]   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error:
subprocess-exited-with-error × Getting requirements to build wheel did
not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> See above for output. note:
This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem
with pip.

